# Trying to login-in in the Ubuntu tty

Tags: terminal

I am having some trouble starting the recently upgraded Ubuntu. So, I try to boot in recovery mode, and start a terminal (with Ctrl + Alt + F1). However, when the terminal starts, I get the prompt

```
Username:$login:
```

but it doesn't get my usual username. When I type it + Return, it doesn't ask for my password.

How can I login in this case?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you are seeing at the virtual console?  That doesn't look anything like the normal output of the login prompt.

Comment: Depending on what entails recovery mode in Ubuntu, it's entirely possible that only root will be allowed to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Does your regular user have a password?

If not, i doubt you can login using your tty.

However you can try this:

Reboot, on grub menu type **e**, then go to the kernel entry and again type **e**, at the end of the line add **rw init=/bin/bash**, then hit **b** for boot using the recent edited line.

This will give you a root terminar, then you can set you password using **passwd**

Regards!